# JQuery DataTables mRender button - how do I get button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax call:

```
    $('#stlmtddel').click(function(event) {
        var customerid = "<%=customerid%>";
        var appointofcaid = "<%=appointofcaid%>";
        var kindcontrolid = "<%=kindcontrolid%>";
        var auditorid = "<%=auditorid%>";
        var instype = "view";

        $.ajax({
                 type: 'GET',
                 url: 'crudsettlement.jsp',
                 data: {
                     Wcustomerid: customerid,
                     Wappointofcaid: appointofcaid,
                     Wkindcontrolid: kindcontrolid,
                     Wauditorid: auditorid,
                     Winstype: instype
                 },
                 async: false,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(json) {

                     $('#settlementsd').DataTable({
                         destroy: true,
                         "stateSave": true,
                         "displayLength": 10,
                         "lengthMenu": [
                             [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
                             [10, 25, 50, 100, "όλα"]
                         ],
                         "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                         "language": {
                             "emptyTable": "Δεν βρέθηκαν δεδομένα",
                             "thousands": ".",
                             "lengthMenu": "Εμφάνιση _MENU_ εγγραφών ανά σελίδα",
                             "zeroRecords": "Δεν βρέθηκαν εγγραφές - ",
                             "info": "Εμφανίζονται οι εγγραφές _START_ έως _END_ από σύνολο _TOTAL_",
                             "infoEmpty": "Εμφανίζονται οι εγγραφές 0 έως 0 από σύνολο 0",
                             "infoFiltered": "(Εφαρμόστηκε φίλτρο σε σύνολο _MAX_ εγγραφών)",
                             "search": "Αναζήτηση:",
                             "paginate": {
                                 "first": "Αρχή",
                                 "previous": "Προηγούμενη",
                                 "next": "Επόμενη",
                                 "last": "Τέλος"
                             }
                         },
                         "aaData": json,
                         "aoColumns": [{
                             "mData": "auditoridid"
                         }, {
                             "mData": "auditoridname"
                         }, {
                             "mData": "sdpaymentnet"
                         }, {
                             "mData": "sdpaymenttax"
                         }, {
                             "mData": "sdpayment"
                         }, {
                             "bSortable": false,
                             "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                                 return '<input type="hidden" name="Wauditordid" class="Cauditordid" value="'+row.auditoridid+'" disabled><button type="submit" id="stlmtddel" class="btn btn-danger" formnovalidate><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>';
                             }
                         }, ]
                     });
                     alert(json.msg);
                 }

             });
   });
```

In mRender I create a button wiht id="stlmtddel" and I want to get the click event. I tryied the following:
`$('#stlmtddel').click(function(event) {
}`

but not working for all rows. 
for example if the table have 3 rows and I tried to click to delete one of that rows this working fine.
After that the table have 2 rows and when I tried to click to delete one of that rows then the click event not working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to HTML specification `ID` [must be unique](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127180). As there are three buttons with same id, so, `$("#stlmtddel")` will only match first occurrence thus click event only works for first button.

Use class `stlmtddel` instead of id `stlmtddel`, As id must be unique within webpage.

```
 $('#settlementsd').DataTable({
     ...
     "aoColumns": [
         ...
         {
             "bSortable": false,
             "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                   return '<input type="hidden" name="Wauditordid" class="Cauditordid" value="'+row.auditoridid+'" disabled><button type="submit" class="stlmtddel btn btn-danger" formnovalidate><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>';
              }
          }
     ]
 });
```

After that you can listen to button click by listening to click event on `#settlementsd`

```
$('#settlementsd').on('click', '.stlmtddel', function() {
    // Button click logic goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try datatable fnRowCallback, if you want to use callback of mRender.

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html